# Identify this radioactive-particle filter?

Tags: radioactivity

I am wondering if anyone can provide further info as to the preliminary principle involved in the filter shown below, any internet links would be appreciated. Is taken from a magazine related to Titanium magazine

[image]

Comment: There is plenty of articles in the Internet about radioactive particle detection, filtering, but no description of the specific device you ask about. What is known to you that this filter does? Selects a certain type of particles? Detects a certain type? You should give more details.

Comment: I don't see any electrical connections -- it might just be a normal filter which is designed to capture any small particle, including radioactive ones.

Comment: No, electrical connections may be unnecessary, the device seems like a portable object and may work on battery. On the other hand, I saw radiation filters for placing at windows, and they look WIDE, not a thin apparatus as in the picture.